# Cannot enable the scrollbar in Tkinter TreeView

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Currently, the book data is displayed via TKinter TreeView.
As the dataset contain many column, i am trying to add a horizontal scroll bar with below attempt. Yet, the scroll bar dont seems to be working. Any idea on this? Thanks

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd 
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
    
root = tk.Tk()    
out = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfmean = out
cols = list(out.columns)        
        
cols = list(out.columns)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode='browse')
tree.place(x=30, y=95)

tree["columns"] = cols
for i in cols:
    tree.column(i, anchor="w")
    tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')

for index, row in dfmean.iterrows():
    tree.insert("",0,text=index,values=list(row))

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=tree.yview)
vsb.place(x=30+200+2, y=95, height=200+20)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    
    
root.mainloop()
```

Current Output
[image]

Comment: It is visible you have placed in between two columns so that's where it would appear

Comment: May i know how can i place the scrollbar underneath all the column, so that it can be scrolled horizontally

Comment: Do you really want to use the place? You could use pack() and achieve the same  quicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`place` uses absolute positioning which is not really of much use as it doesn't handle resizing automatically whereas `pack()` and `grid()` does it for you. For horizontal scroll bar, you need to set `command=tree.xview` instead of `command=tree.yview` and instead of `tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)` it must be `tree.configure(xscrollcommand=vsb.set)`.

also, you need to set stretch for the column as False manually otherwise the column width will be adjusted when the widget is resized (`tree.column(i, anchor="w",  stretch=False)`).

```py
import pandas as pd 
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

data={'Id': [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 10], 'Names':['Tom', 'Rob', 'Tim', 'Jim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim'],
      'Column': [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9],'Noo': ['Tom', 'Rob', 'Tim', 'Jim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim']}
 
root = tk.Tk()
out = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfmean = out
cols = list(out.columns)        
        
cols = list(out.columns)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode='browse')
#tree.place(x=30, y=95)
tree.pack(side='top')

tree["columns"] = cols
for i in cols:
    tree.column(i, anchor="w",  stretch=False)
    tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')

for index, row in dfmean.iterrows():
    tree.insert("",0,text=index,values=list(row))

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
vsb.pack(fill='x')
tree.configure(xscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    
    
root.mainloop()
```